# SQL CASE with multiple THENS gives incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, case

I'm trying to do this CASE statement in SQL but it is incorrect syntax, what is wrong? Is there a way to do this with SQL?

```
CASE    
    WHEN @TESTVALUE LIKE 'a%'
    OR @TESTVALUE LIKE 'b%' THEN
        RETURN
    WHEN @TESTVALUE LIKE 'c%' THEN
        SET @var1 = 'var1c'
        SET @var2 = 'var2c' 
    ELSE 
        SET @var1 = 'var1other'
        SET @var2 = 'var2other' 
END
```

Comment: Then `return`?  What is that?  What database are you using.  Do you intend a `case` expression (which is standard SQL) or a `case` statement, which is in the scripting language.

Comment: The return is just to exit the script. 
I’m not sure in the difference between the two case types. I just want a java like switch/case statement to set these 2 variables on those conditions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a break like that.

split it in 2 parts

`Case 
    WHEN @TESTVALUE NOT LIKE 'a%' AND @TESTVALUE NOT LIKE 'b%'
    THEN 
       CASE <rest of the stuff> 
       END 
 END`